# Unique data from three different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three table named "Public", "Private" and "Normal". The priority of tables are Private has high than normal and public. Each table may or may not have duplicate data. My question is 
if all table has same data it should return from high priority table only not from all.
For Example

```
PRIVATE TABLE
==============================
id           |  Mobileno
==============================
1            | 9999999999
------------------------------
2            | 8888888888
------------------------------


NORMAL TABLE
==============================
id           |  Mobileno
==============================
1            | 9999999988
------------------------------
2            | 8888888888
------------------------------


PUBLIC TABLE
==============================
id           |  Mobileno
==============================
1            | 9999999977
------------------------------
2            | 8888888888
------------------------------
```

I want result like

```
==============================
 Mobileno      |  type
==============================
 9999999999    | private
------------------------------
 8888888888    | private
------------------------------
 9999999988    | normal
------------------------------
 9999999977    | public
```

Comment: Spreading this data across separate tables violates the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design).  Don't do it.  Instead, put all of the data in a single table with an additional `type` column: you can then filter as desired by grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select t1.Mobileno,
case when t1.Mobileno in (select Mobileno from PRIVATE) then 'PRIVATE' 
when t1.Mobileno not in (select Mobileno from PRIVATE) 
and t1.Mobileno in (select Mobileno from NORMAL) then 'NORMAL'
else 'PUBLIC' end as type
from
(select * from PRIVATE
union
select * from NORMAL
union
select * from PUBLIC)t1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/516be/19)